# Is there a way to activate a Button that exists within another class?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using C# and Xamarin. I have two separate classes. One class is essentially the user interface and another class is acting as a custom built generic entry for users to input data and search for results by clicking a button.

Main UI Class:

```
Class MainPage
{
   public MainPage
   {
      Content = new StackLayout
      {
         Children =
         {
            new InputClass // This is my custom built user entry class
            {
            }.Invoke(ic => ic.Clicked += WhenButtonPressedMethod) // The problem is here, I can't figure out how to call the button within the input class to fire a clicked event.
         }
      }
   }
}

public async void WhenButtonPressedMethod (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Supposed to do stuff when the button is pressed
}
```

InputClass:

```
public class InputClass : Grid
{
   public delegate void OnClickedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
   public event OnClickHandler Clicked;

   public InputClass
   {
      Children.Add(
      new Button {}
      .Invoke(button => button.Clicked += Button_Clicked)
      )
   }

   private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Clicked?.Invoke(this, e);
   }
}
```

The "InputClass" is a grid that holds a title text label, an entry and a button that a user can press to submit and search data. The button in this class is what I'm trying to actually access to invoke/cause a click event so that the method in the main UI class can be called. But, when I try to invoke a click event on the "InputClass" I can't access the button inside of it, I can only access "InputClass" itself which is just a grid with no useful event properties.

Any solutions or ideas?

---

If you are running into the same problem as mentioned here, follow the code on this page and read through the comments, it covers enough to be able to piece it together. My mistake was attaching Invokes to the wrong objects.

Comment: InputClass needs to raise a custom event when the button is pressed that the consumer class can subscribe to.  The consumer does not need to know the details of what is inside InputClass.

Comment: I figured as much. I've actually tried implementing that, but what I've done so far hasn't worked. I created a "public event EventHandler Clicked" event inside of InputClass and tried calling it through the Invoke "InputClass => InputClass.Clicked += Method", but every time I try calling it, it doesn't actually call the method. I'm assuming I need to add code somewhere, but I'm not sure what. From examples I've found online, I still can't piece it together.

Comment: you need to wire up the Button's Clicked event to raise your custom event

Comment: Yup I did that too. My button goes like this: "Button => Button.Clicked += Button_Clicked". Then Button_Clicked is a method which does this: "private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { Clicked?.Invoke(this, e); }. The "Clicked?" is my "public event OnClickHandler Clicked;". Now if I don't add the question mark, it gives me an object reference error. If I include the question mark, it runs fine but does not do anything because Clicked is null for some reason.

Comment: please [edit] your question to include additional details or code, don't stuff it into comments

Comment: I edited the post a bit. There is a lot more code in the classes that is extremely irrelevant and would just take up space so I only put what should be relevant.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the Clicked handler in your page?

Comment: I might not be... I thought that was what the ".Invoke(InputClass => InputClass.Clicked += WhenButtonPressedMethod)" would do.

Comment: Intellisense will automatically recognized the ".Clicked" event when I use it in Invoke. When I type "InputClass.", Clicked comes up as an event option.

Comment: I’m not that familiar with the fluent syntax you’re using, but using “InputClass” inside the Invoke looks suspicious because that is already the name of a class.  But I may be wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that, in my actual code it is different from "InputClass". I edited it once more.

Comment: I haven't used [fluent markup's Invoke syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/markup#logic-integration) either, but the usage looks correct. If put breakpoint inside `Button_Clicked`, is it reached? Is the event `Clicked` non-null? If you F11, does it go into the caller's method? Does `WhenButtonPressedMethod` have the appropriate parameters?

Comment: try `public event EventHandler Clicked;`

Comment: Yes I've tried debugging by putting a "Console.WriteLine("Button was clicked.")" which it definitely does reach and prints out within the Button_Clicked method. I can also confirm the event is null. I put an if statement to check if(Clicked != null) and it was false.

Comment: @Jason I changed it to "EventHandler" but I get the same results. It still gets to the Button_Clicked method and the "Clicked" event is still null.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Also, the WhenButtonPressedMethod doesn't ever get called. That is where the disconnect seems to be. The event has always been null and the code breaks when I don't check to make sure it's not null because of the NullReferenceException error.

Comment: The null is because the handler isn’t getting assigned.  I’d try an old school event handler assignment instead of using fluent.  Otherwise I’ll have another look in the morning

Comment: Ok, any chance you could point me in the direction of some old school event handling examples? This is the only syntax I've been familiar with thus far in figuring this out. I really appreciate the help by the way, I've been looking at this for a while now and this is the first time I've ever posted to StackOverflow.

Comment: I've added an answer that shows the "old school" assigning of event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why fluent `Invoke` didn't work correctly.
Add the event handlers this way:

```cs
public MainPage
{
    var ic = new InputClass();
    ic.Clicked += WhenButtonPressedMethod;
    Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = { ic }
    }
}

public InputClass
{
    var button = new Button;
    button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;
    Children.Add(button);
}
```